# How do I obtain data from three tables in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have three tables:

1. gallery_items
2. gallery_album_items
3. gallery_tags

I've managed to join the first two tables but how do I add the gallery_tags table to the following query?:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM gallery_items
RIGHT JOIN gallery_album_items 
ON gallery_items.id=gallery_album_items.id 
WHERE gallery_items.name LIKE '%{$term}%' 
OR gallery_items.description LIKE '%{$term}%'
```

Essentially what I want to add:

```sql
OR gallery_tags.tag LIKE '%{$term}%'
```

The table structures

```
gallery_items
id   name     description
12   Sharon   This is sharon's description
26   Rhett    This is rhett's description
33   Lincoln  This is lincoln's description


gallery_album_items
id   album
12   14 
26   12
33   7


gallery_tags
id   item     tag
23   12       blonde
43   26       tall
3    33       glasses
```

Essentially the result I want for a search for "blonde":
**Sharon** is **blonde** and is in **album #14**.

(You don't have to present an echo statement. This is just an example to show you the result.)

**Edit - Final ANSWER**

```
SELECT DISTINCT gallery_items.id 
FROM gallery_items
RIGHT OUTER JOIN gallery_album_items ON gallery_items.id = gallery_album_items.id
LEFT JOIN gallery_tags ON gallery_items.id = gallery_tags.item
WHERE gallery_items.active !=  '0'
AND (gallery_items.name LIKE '%blonde%'
OR gallery_items.description LIKE '%blonde%'
OR gallery_tags.tag LIKE '%blonde%'
```

Comment: Just FYI, note that RIGHT JOINs appear in SO roughly 1/20th as often as LEFT JOINs - just saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *

FROM gallery_items 

RIGHT OUTER JOIN gallery_album_items 

ON gallery_items.id=gallery_album_items.id 

LEFT OUTER JOIN  gallery_tags 

ON gallery_tags.id   =  gallery_album_items.id     

WHERE gallery_items.name LIKE '%{$term}%' 

OR gallery_items.description LIKE '%{$term}%'

OR gallery_tags.tag LIKE '%{$term}%'
```

Answer (score 1):

about this

```sql
SELECT *
FROM gallery_items
RIGHT JOIN gallery_album_items 
   ON gallery_items.id=gallery_album_items.id 
LEFT JOIN gallery_tags
   ON gallery_tags.id = gallery_items.id
WHERE gallery_items.name LIKE '%{$term}%' 
OR gallery_items.description LIKE '%{$term}%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM gallery_items
RIGHT JOIN gallery_album_items 
ON gallery_items.id=gallery_album_items.id
LEFT JOIN gallery_tags on gallery_items.id on gallery_tags.id  
WHERE gallery_items.name LIKE '%{$term}%' 
OR gallery_items.description LIKE '%{$term}%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Try This

```
select gi.name, gai.ablum, gt.tag 
    from 
    gallery_items as gi JOIN gallery_album_items as gai 
    on gt.id=gai.id 
    Join gallery_tags as gt 
    on gi.id=gt.items
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using table name you can use aliases for writing join query for better understanding while thinking about the logic.
I tried following one, hope it would help.

---

create table g_i(
id int,
name varchar(20),
descp nvarchar(max)
)

insert into g_i values(12,'asf 12','description 12')
insert into g_i values(26,'asf 26','description 26')
insert into g_i values(33,'asf 33','description 33')
select *from g_i

---

create table g_a(
id int,
album varchar(20)
)
insert into g_a values(12,'album 12')
insert into g_a values(26,'album 26')
insert into g_a values(33,'album 33')
select *from g_a

---

create table g_t(
id int,
item int,
tag nvarchar(40)
)
insert into g_t values(23,12,'tag 12')
insert into g_t values(43,26,'tag 26')
insert into g_t values(3,33,'tag 33')
select *from g_t

---

SELECT *

FROM g_i as i RIGHT JOIN g_a as a ON i.id=a.id 
LEFT JOIN g_t as t on t.item = i.id

WHERE i.name LIKE '%t%' OR i.descp LIKE '%t%'

---